# Can't unmarshal the file using javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext after changing the version of SPRING to 2.3.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, unmarshalling

I ran into an issue after moving the version of SPRING from 2.1.4.RELEASE to 2.3.0.RELEASE. Now when I try to unmarshal the simple XML Invoice File with the info needed to populate this object it can't recognize them for some reason and is setting all of them to NULL. The versions of the **JAXB** I'm using:

```
   <!--       Needed for namespace mapping-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
```

[image]

And here is the same method call when moving to the old spring version (2.1.4.RELEASE)... As you can see, it mapped the data correctly...
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

If someone needs some additional info, I'll add them.

Here is the code I use to unmarshal the data:

```
  */
@Override
public EDIFile createEDIFile(String filename, String payload, Source source, Map<ConfigKey, Object> routeConfiguration) throws EDIException {
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    try {
        unmarshaller = getContext(source).createUnmarshaller();
        Object document = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(payload.getBytes()));
        if (document instanceof JAXBElement) {
            return (EDIFile) ((JAXBElement<?>) document).getValue();
        } else {
            return (EDIFile) document;
        }
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new EDIException("An error occured while creating a file " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The pictures above are just showing the content in debugger mode when taking the part after unmarshalling

Comment: There is no code, no config in your question. Only hard to see screenshots. Also did you "only" upgrade Spring Boot or did other things as well? JDK, Dependencies?

Comment: The only thing I changed is the spring version, as soon as I move it back to 2.1.4.RELEASE it works as expected... but for some other purposes, I need a 2.3.0 version so I can't go back to 2.1.4...

Comment: Please add some code (the endpoint) and config you are using. Also you might want to try 2.3.3 (the most recent version).

Comment: I've added the code where I'm trying to unmarshal the data... I tried the 2.3.3 version too, it didn't help...

Comment: What I'm interested in is how this is called, is this a `@(Rest)Controller` or integration endpoint or ...

Comment: this is a CAMEL integration, it is collecting the file from the queue, and trying to process it, it gets the XML file correctly, but when it tries to pass the file data inside this unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(payload.getBytes())); it is not able to unmarshal it correctly, while when lowering the version this part passes easily...

Comment: Does camel support this version of Spring Boot? Or does upgrading Spring Boot also lead to an upgraded camel starter?

Comment: yes, camel supports this version, the camel version is 2.23.1

Comment: the fact that things are empty makes me wonder if the integration is correct. The issue imho isn't the marshalling but rather calling the method with an empty payload (at least that is what I suspect) or the payload has an encoding that isn't recognized.